# Dealing with Scope in Object methods containing 'this' keyword called by Event Listeners 

Tags: javascript, oop, events, scope

I've generalized my lack of understanding of the situation to this small problem. Here's what I think I know so far:

I have an object `myDog` (a global variable). `Dog` has a member variable `el` that is an html element; because it's an element, I can add event listeners to it. So, when you click on `myDog.el`, it logs to the console the values of `this.name` and `myDog.name`. As expected because of scope, `this.name` is undefined and `myDog.name` is 'tye'. `this` inside of `Dog.speak` when invoked by the click event listener refers to the element that was clicked, the member variable `el`, not the object `Dog`. Since `myDog` is a global variable, it's able to pick back up regardless of the function's scope and get to `myDog.name` just fine.

See code below:

```
function Dog(name,id) {
    this.name = name ? name : "spot";
    this.id = id ? id : "dog";
    this.el = document.getElementById(this.id); // given there is a div with a matching    
    this.el.addEventListener("click",this.speak); // ignore IE for simplicity (attachEvent has its own 'this' scope issues)
}

Dog.prototype = {
    speak: function() {
        console.log("this.name: "+this.name+"\nmyDog.name: "+myDog.name);
    }
};

var myDog = new Dog("tye","dog1");
```

So... my questions are

1) What are some strategies for attaching objects to html elements, so that I can go from `this.el` back to `myDog` (`this.el`'s owner) without `myDog` being a global variable?

2) Are global variables in this case a necessary evil? And if so, what are so good strategies in this case to gracefully use them? For example, what if I wanted 100 dogs instantiated? How would I handle all those global variables in `Dog.speak`?

Here's a jsfiddle version if you want to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/chadhutchins/Ewgw5/

Comment: One of the most common ways of getting around scope problems with this is assigning 'this' to a variable at the start of a function...self will always refer to the original this.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but will you explain that a bit further? How can I use that technique in the example above.

Comment: I also do as Pastor Bones said

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *"1) What are some strategies for attaching objects to html elements..."*

Since you're using `.addEventListener()`, I'd suggest taking advantage of a feature of it that few people seem to know about... making your `Dog` object implement the `EventListener` interface.

This establishes a very clean relationship between your `Dog` data and its associated element.

Only minor changes are required. Code first... explanation below.

---

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/Ewgw5/1/

```
function Dog(name,id) {
    this.name = name ? name : "spot";
    this.id = id ? id : "dog";
    this.el = document.getElementById(this.id);

    // ---------------------------------v----no function!
    this.el.addEventListener("click", this);
}

Dog.prototype = {
    // Implement the `EventListener` interface   
    handleEvent: function(event) {
        switch (event.type) {
            case "click": return this.speak();
        }
    },
    speak: function() {
        console.log("this.name: "+this.name+"\nmyDog.name: "+myDog.name);
    }
};

var myDog = new Dog("tye","dog1");
```

---

So all I did was pass `this` in the constructor to `addEventListener()` instead of passing a function, and then I added a `handleEvent()` method to `Dog.prototype`.

Now when a `"click"` event occurs, it will invoke the `handleEvent()` method. The value of `this` in that method will be your `Dog` instance. So from there you can call whatever method(s) you need.

Because you made the element a property of `this`, you can access the element via `this.el`. But that's technically not even necessary, since the element is also available via the `event` object as `event.currentTarget`.

---

> *"2) Are global variables in this case a necessary evil..."*

Thankfully no!

---

This behavior should be part of your shim for `.addEventListener()`.

Comment: Good way for object-oriented event handling. In case you have several instances listening to the same event, but you handle it differently depending on the local fields of the instances.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
function Dog(name,id) {
   var self = this;   // <---- NEW BIT saving a reference to this
   this.name = name || "spot"; // <-- unrelated tidy-up to use || instead of ?:
   this.id = id || "dog";
   this.el = document.getElementById(this.id); // given there is a div with a matching    
   this.el.addEventListener("click",function(){ self.speak(); });
        // ignore IE for simplicity (attachEvent has its own 'this' scope issues)
}
```

Through the magic of closures the anonymous function I've added within `addEventListener()` has access to the scope of the containing function even after the containing function returns, so it is able to use `self` which holds a reference to the original object saved from `this` when `Dog()` was called as a constructor.

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't directly address the questions you numbered (1) and (2), but as you can see you don't need global variables to fix this this issue. With the technique I described you could instantiate 100 dogs and they'd all work. (Well, they'd all speak anyway: they'd all work if you added `Dog.prototype.work = function() { }`.)

Comment: Thanks for explaining it beyond "magic of closures". It really does make sense. Also, thanks for the tip on the member variable cleanup.

Comment: Just to clarify. When a function is called, "this" within the function is bound to the object that owns the reference that was used to call the function.

Comment: Bearing in mind that you can use [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply) or [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to set `this` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

```
 this.el.addEventListener("click", this.speak.bind(this));
```

This way is preferable because it doesn't require allocating a scope in order to pass the binding. Scope allocation is one of the more costly things in JS.

Comment: This is by far the cleanest solution of the provided answers and is the best solution I am aware of.