# Javascript Class & EventListener

Tags: javascript

I have a basic javascript class with two properties. I want to log the value of one on a click event. Here is what I got:

```
function Clicker(/*string*/var1, /*id*/var2) {
    this.name = var1;
    this.clickerid = var2;
    this.clickevent = function() {
        console.log("1: " + this.name);
        console.log("2: " + this);
        console.log("3: " + window.testClicker.name);
    };

    var element = document.getElementById(this.clickerid);
    element.addEventListener("click", this.clickevent, false);
}

window.onload = function() {
    window.testClicker = new Clicker("lorem ipsum", "checkbox1");
};

<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
```

When I run my test I see the following in the log:

```
1: undefined
2: <input id=​"checkbox1" type=​"checkbox" value=​"1" checked>​
3: lorem ipsum
```

I was expecting to see the first and third lines match. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `this` depends on the context in which a function is called.

When the event listener fires, the function is called in the context of the element the event is associated with - not the object the function was copied from.

Use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to override the context (it generates a new function that calls the original function in whatever context you define).

```
element.addEventListener("click", this.clickevent.bind(this), false);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
element.addEventListener(
    "click", 
    function (context) {
        return function () {
            context.clickevent();
        };
    }(this),
    false
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This works as expected now.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be a [context](http://joshuakehn.com/2011/10/20/Understanding-JavaScript-Context.html) issue, could the following work:

```
function Clicker(/*string*/var1, /*id*/var2) {
    this.name = var1;
    this.clickerid = var2;
    var self = this;
    this.clickevent = function() {
        console.log("1: " + self.name);
        console.log("2: " + this);
        console.log("3: " + window.testClicker.name);
    };

    var element = document.getElementById(this.clickerid);
    element.addEventListener("click", this.clickevent, false);
}
```

as you can see with the 2nd `console.log`, `this` refers to the checkbox, not the `Cliker` object

Comment: It isn't scope, it is context.

Comment: @Quentin I've seen controversies about calling it "context" too (although several libraries do that). Some say it might be confused with "execution context". I personally have been using "`this` value", which is very close to what the spec calls it.

Comment: This approach worked. Thanks. But I'm sticking with the approach shown above by Quentin since there is one less variable to define.

Comment: Actually, after playing with this for a bit. I like this approach as equally as much. When I don't bind, I have a useful way to operate on the checkbox element itself AND access to the class object through self.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, there are three possible solutions:

1. Using a closured variable as suggested in [dm03514's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18836967/825789).
2. Using `bind` as suggested in [Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18837009/825789).
3. Using the event listener interface / `handleEvent` as suggested at [Dealing with Scope in Object methods containing 'this' keyword called by Event Listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336779/dealing-with-scope-in-object-methods-containing-this-keyword-called-by-event-l) .