# JavaScript classes and EventListeners

Tags: javascript, class, dom-events

I'm trying to use JavaScript class architecture in combination with `addEventListener` such that I can define a series of class methods once, which will be applied to all appropriate HTML and/or CSS objects. Below is an example with ONLY one circle, which should toggles red or blue when clicked. Unfortunately, as is, the class does architecture is unable to properly communicate with the DOM.

I've chosen to write the script in-line just to explore the basic concept more easily rather than juggling around multiple files for purposes of question cohesion (I do realize that in actuality, I'd likely use separate HTML and JS files.)

I'd like to code as is to be edited such that the circle changes color when clicked. (Also, the code DID function when class architecture was not used. I can add that if it's useful.)

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #555;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Circle CSS</h2>
<div class="circle"></div>
<script>

class GameObject{
  constructor(shape){
    this.shape = shape;
    this.clicks = 0;
  };
  clickEvent(){
    this.shape.addEventListener('click',function(){
      this.clicks += 1
      if (this.clicks % 2 == 1){
        this.shape.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }else{
        this.shape.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      }
    })
  };
};

let shape = document.querySelector('.circle')
let s = new GameObject(shape);

console.log(s);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, the following questions/answers went above my head, though they are related:
[Javascript Class & EventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836925/javascript-class-eventlistener)
[Dealing with Scope in Object methods containing 'this' keyword called by Event Listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336779/dealing-with-scope-in-object-methods-containing-this-keyword-called-by-event-l)

Edit: I took advice from comment and added `clickEvent()` into this constructor. However, the following error was triggered:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (circle.html:31)
```

Comment: You never call the clickEvent method so the event listener will never fire. Try calling the method within the constructor as well.

Comment: `this` is not the `s` instance of `GameObject`; it is the element. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #555;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Circle CSS</h2>
<div class="circle"></div>
<script>

class GameObject{
  constructor(shape){
    this.shape = shape;
    this.clicks = 0;
    this.clickEvent(); // call the method to add the listener
  };
  clickEvent(){
    this.shape.addEventListener('click',function(){
      this.clicks += 1
      if (this.clicks % 2 == 1){
        this.shape.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }else{
        this.shape.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      }
    }.bind(this)) // bind callback function to the the correct 'this' context
  };
};

let shape = document.querySelector('.circle')
let s = new GameObject(shape);

console.log(s);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the name `clickEvent` to `handleEvent`, and move the `.addEventListener` call outside the class.

Then instead of a function, pass your `GameObject` instance as the event handler, and it'll work.

You don't event need to pass the element to the constructor that way. It's available from the `event` object defined on the `handleEvent` method.

```js
class GameObject {
  constructor() {
    this.clicks = 0;
  };

  // Implement the EventListener interface
  handleEvent(event) {
    const shape = event.currentTarget;
    this.clicks += 1

    shape.style.backgroundColor = this.clicks % 2 == 1 ? 'red' : 'blue';

    console.log(this); // `this` is your class instance
  };
};

let g = new GameObject();

document.querySelector('.circle')
        .addEventListener("click", g); // use the object as the handler

console.log(g);
```

```css
.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #555;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Circle CSS</h2>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

What's happening here is that by naming the method `handleEvent`, you're causing your `GameObject` class to implement the *EventListener* interface. Therefore *instances* of that class are eligible to be used as an event handler instead of a function.

Answer (score 0):

1. You never call the function `clickEvent`.
2. The handler of `addEventListener` uses its own context, to solve this you can either declare a variable `let that = this` and then use it inside of the handler, or you can use an arrow function in order to use the right context (instance of GameObject).

*This approach uses an arrow function*

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #555;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Circle CSS</h2>
<div class="circle"></div>
<script>

class GameObject{
  constructor(shape){
    this.shape = shape;
    this.clicks = 0;
  };
  clickEvent(){
    this.shape.addEventListener('click',() => {
      this.clicks += 1
      if (this.clicks % 2 == 1){
        this.shape.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }else{
        this.shape.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      }
    })
  };
};

let shape = document.querySelector('.circle')
let s = new GameObject(shape);
s.clickEvent();

console.log(s);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We're moving in the right direction! However, `circle.html:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (circle.html:30)`